# How can I get fixed output from my django database

Tags: python, django, database, string-formatting

Not so long time ago I started programming on Django Framework.
I have a model `Questions` with 2 attributes - `question_text` and `id`.
When my view works - in browser I see output smth like this:

```
[< Questions: First question >, < Questions: Second question >, < Questions:Third question >]
```

But I just want to see:

```
First question, Second question, Third question.
```

What should I do to fix it? Smth with `__str__` function in model or what?

Answer (score 1):

```
question = Questions.objects.all()
```

returns a queryset which you obviously print in your template. Try iterating over your queryset in your html template like:

```
{% for q in questions %}
   {{ q.question_text }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps.